# Question about web programming, maps to be specific

Tags: maps

The prof gave us an assigment to finish in the next couple of months, we have to write a web app that is basically a mapping system for a floor of a building. Like a very very simple version of google maps, people need to be able to look up a room and be able to get directions from one part of the floor to another. I have never done any major web programming and don't even know how to start. Is there a google maps or mapquest API that I can use or do I have to start it from scratch? I'm not asking anyone to solve it for me, just nudge me in the right direction so as where to start.

Comment: I don't think the Google Maps API or MapQuest is going to help you much regarding routing. They only work with their own databases of streets.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific as to what you're having problems with? Making a web interface? Implementing a pathfinding algorithm?

Comment: I've never done any major web programming and I have no idea how to build the physical interface of the map. I was hoping google maps had an api that would allow me to add information from the map of the floor that I need to build and build the map for me.

Comment: Google Maps will require you to either generate your own tiles (the small square images that make up the map) or make the entire thing out of PolyLines (not a good idea). IMO making your own map view would be a very good exercise in JavaScript programming, if that's part of what you're supposed to learn.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest thinking of the task as three parts:

1. Displaying the image of the map
   (probably, for best efficiency, as
   lazily-loaded tiles like Google Maps
   does)
2. Representing the rooms and the
   connections between them, probably
   as a [graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29).  Using a graph
   allows you to easily use a
   well-documented algorithm like
   [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_star) or [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) to find
   the shortest route from point A to
   point B.
3. Converting from a click on the image
   to a node on the graph, and from a
   node on the graph to a point in the
   image.  Probably each node should
   just store a pair of (x,y)
   coordinates.

With an arrangement like this, all your code has to do is:

```
The first time the user clicks
{
  Identify the nearest node to their click as node A;
}
The second time the user clicks
{
  Identify the nearest node to their click as node B;
  Use Dijkstras Algorithm or A* to find the shortest route from node A to node B;
  For each edge in the resulting route
  {
    Add a line to the image of the map;
  }
  Mark node A with a green dot and node B with a red dot (or something);
}
```

Comment: Jon nails this.  Your question, as original asked, reads to us as "oh my God, help!"  Split the question into multiple parts, and ask more focused things.